# Error: no se puede hacer cast

Tags: java, android

Estoy implementando el Navigation Drawer en mi aplicación. Solo que me da error al dar click en alguno de mis items.

Aquí el código:

```
public class MainActivityMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
Toolbar toolbar;
ProgressDialog dialog;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();


    /*DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = img.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = 100;
    img.setLayoutParams(params);*/
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivityMenu.this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();


    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
    TextView Usuario = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    Usuario.setText( "Usuario: " + settings.getString("ONControlUsuarioLogin",""));

}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String evento = String.valueOf(((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtevento)).getText());
      selectItem(position);

    }

}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
  /*  Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ClientesFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);*/
    //android.app.Fragment fragment1 = null;


    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Prueba1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //fragment = new ConnectFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ClientesFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("O_DetalleMenu", (DetalleMenu)((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lismenu)).getTag());
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            // fragment = new ClientesFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            //fragment = new TableFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        //setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Adjnto codigo de Layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</FrameLayout>



<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerPane"
    android:layout_gravity="start">



<!-- Profile Box -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/profileBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_oncontrol"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Usuario"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />


</RelativeLayout>


<ListView

    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/profileBox"
    android:background="@color/ColorBackground1"/>

    <!--  <include
          android:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
          />
-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y el error

```
07-25 13:09:39.312 15344-15344/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol, PID: 15344
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1415)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1630)
    at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.MainActivityMenu.selectItem(MainActivityMenu.java:125)
    at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.MainActivityMenu.access$000(MainActivityMenu.java:29)
    at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.MainActivityMenu$DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivityMenu.java:72)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías añadir el código de xml para el drawer_layout ya que no se ve que aparezca en el layout

Comment: ya lo añadi como imagen

Comment: @HugoRodriguez Hugo, agregalo como texto y completo por favor!.

Answer (score 1):

`android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams` y `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams` son 2 clases diferentes aunque tengan el mismo nombre. Importa solo la clase que vas a utilizar cuando vayas a asignar los parametros del layout en el DrawerLayout, en este caso `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams`